# Getting two errors when trying to return values

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a program that can perform the following objectives.:

**1. Inside the `main` method:**

1.1 Declare an integer array of five elements and populate it by five random integers between 1 to 100.

1.2 Create an object of `Largest` class.

1.3 Pass the array in step 1.1 by calling the `LargestElement(int[] MyArray)` method.

1.4 Print the return value of `LargestElement(int[] MyArray)`

**2. Inside the `LargestElement(int[] MyArray)` method:**

2.1 Find the largest element in the array.

2.2 Return the element.

The following is the code that I've put together so far.

```
public class Largest {  

    public int LargestElement(int[] myArray) {

        int largest;

        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
            if (myArray[i] > largest) {
                largest = myArray[i];
            }
        return largest;
    }   

    public static void main (String[] args) {   

        int[] MyArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        int largestelement = 0;

        largestelement = LargestElement(int[] MyArray);

        System.out.println (largestelement);
    }
}
```

The only issue I can notice is the `largestelement = LargestElement(int MyArray);` keeps telling me that `.class is expected.` Am I supposed to declare something else? Also, it's saying that I need another semicolon on that line but I really don't know how to approach that.

Edit: So I have been told that I have two options: make the method I are calling `LargestElement` static or create an object of Largest and use it to call `LargestElement().` I would prefer to create an object.

As I understand it, I only need to edit the code to say

```
public class Largest {  

    public int LargestElement(int[] myArray) {

   int largest = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
      if (myArray[i] > largest) {
      largest = myArray[i];
      }
      return largest;
        }   


    public static void main (String[] args) {   

    Largest largest = new Largest();

    int[] MyArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    int largestelement = 0;

    largestelement = largest.LargestElement(MyArray);

    System.out.println (largestelement);
    }
}
```

Edit: Changed line three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the class `int[]` as parameter for `LargestElement` which is unnecessary and you only need to pass the variable `MyArray`

You are also calling a non-static method from your class `Largest` without an instantiated object of class `Largest`. If you want don't want to create an object of `Largest` then you need to make the method `LargestElement(int[] myArray)` static. Otherwise you will need to create an object of `Largest` and use it to call `LargestElement(int[] myArray)`

You could do one of the following in your main:

1. Make LargestElement static:

   `public static int LargestElement(int[] myArray)`

Then call it by:

`largestelement = Largest.LargestElement(MyArray);`

(You can ommit the class prefix at the beginning if its inside the same class)

2. Create an object of `Largest` in main and use it to call `LargestElement`

`Largest largest = new Largest();`

`largestelement = largest.LargestElement(MyArray);`

Edit: You also haven't initialized your variable `int largest` in the method `LargestElement()` Since the method cannot return null and your loop block isn't guaranteed to give `largest` a value before returning it, you must give it an initial value e.g `int largest = 0`

As a side note, your naming conventions are incorrect for Java. For methods and variables please use lower camel case i.e `myMethod`, `myVariable`and for class names use upper camel case i.e `MyClass`

Comment: I think I follow. So, following what you said I replaced what I believe are the appropriate lines. Is this correct, as I am now getting three new errors.

`public class Largest { 

 public int LargestElement(int[] myArray) {
   
...
    largestelement = largest.LargestElement(MyArray);
    
    System.out.println (largestelement);
 }
}`

I also tried to adhere to the naming conventions this time around. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Maybe add an edit to your question with the new code. I gave you two options: make the method you are calling `LargestElement` static or create an object of `Largest` and use it to call `LargestElement()`

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I'll be sure to do that.

Comment: Noticed another error in your `LargestElement` method, see my edit.

Comment: Would I just do that on line three?

Comment: In place of your current variable `int largest;` on line 3 yes. In regards to your current edit, the object you created `Largest largest = new Largest();` should be in your main method.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty bad with terminology. Which lines qualify as my main method? Is it solely line 2?

Comment: Inside your `public static void main (String[] args)` method ?

Comment: So I would be replacing line 2 with `Largest largest = new Largest();`?

Comment: Edit: Sorry, getting a bit confused. I would replace the method with `Largest largest = new Largest();.`

Comment: No, the object `Largest largest` should be inside your `main` method. Line 3 I was referring to your int variable `int largest` which you have corrected in your edit.

Comment: How would I go about putting that inside my main method? I don't think I've ever done that before.

Comment: I mean to put your `Largest largest = new Largest();` inside the `main` block of code. I've edited your code in the second edit of your question (may take a couple of minutes to go through).

Comment: Thanks so much for the patience. It's working perfectly. Such a small issue can be easy to overlook.

Comment: No problem. If mine or Orel Eraki's answers helped, consider choosing a best answer (the tick) so others can see what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment specified, you have a an extra `int []` when calling method `LargestElement`.

When calling a method, you only need to specify the values you want the method to be called with. i.e `largestelement = LargestElement(MyArray)`

While declaring a method you need (as you done) to specify the types and the values you want to allow to be passed to the method. i.e:

```
public int LargestElement(int[] myArray) {
```

Comment: I think I follow. Now if I understand you correctly, changing line 21 to     `largestelement = LargestElement(MyArray);` should make the program run correctly, but I am now getting the error `Largest.java:21: error: non-static method LargestElement(int[]) cannot be referenced from a static context.`

What am I overlooking in your statement? Thanks again.

Comment: See my answer @CrickleCrackleCode

Comment: Change LargestElement method to be static as main.